# Graduate in this Spring or graduate this Spring?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

- Graduate in this Spring vs graduate this Spring.
- Graduate in May vs graduate this May.

If they are all correct, then is there any difference in meaning? If there is difference in meaning, when do we need to have a preposition in a sentence like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‘Graduate in May’ implies *this* May. ‘Graduate this May’ is synonymous. Otherwise it is ‘in May next year’ or ‘in May 2023’ etc.

‘Graduate this spring’ is correct. No ‘in’.

Comment: It's all about context, so I'm not necessarily going to contradict you but "Graduate in May" could mean each May, e.g. "Students on this course graduate in May" could mean it happens every year, if it's a general statement about the university calendar, rather than a statement about a particular class or year (in which case it would mean "this May").

Comment: ——That is true.